# Extract a specific value from a string

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing a mentions system, but I can't get the ID directly.

The user ID I select in mentions comes in a String type, as shown in the code below, in the data-id = "1" branch. I intend to get these ID´s all.

Is it possible to extract in this string all the values ​​contained in data-id?

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
 <dx-html-editor (onValueChanged)="ment($event)">
    <dxi-mention
      valueExpr="id" 
      displayExpr="username"
      [dataSource]="allUsers">
     </dxi-mention>
 </dx-html-editor>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  ment(event) {
    if (event != null) {
      console.log(event.value)
    }
  }
```

**STRING**

```
 "<p><span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1">﻿<span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span>﻿</span>  testing <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1">﻿<span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span>﻿</span>  new test <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1">﻿<span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span>﻿</span>  new test <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1">﻿<span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span>﻿</span>  newtest </p>"
```

Comment: please show your datasource value.

Comment: Why is the component emitting an html string? That’s weird component design for angular, would expect a model value of some kind. What lib is this? Might want to consider alternatives tbh

Comment: @bryan60 
you're right ! The library is dev extreme, already researched some mentions in angular, but I couldn't find any that gave me to select the User by name, but pass the ID of this selected user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get matched items from your string using regex `/data-id=\"([0-9a-z]+)\"/gi`

something like this

```
const yourString = `<p><span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1"><span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span></span>  testing <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1"><span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span></span>  new test <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1"><span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span></span>  new test <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="Admin" data-id="1"><span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>Admin</span></span>  newtest </p>`;

const dataIdRegx = /data-id=\"([0-9a-z]+)\"/gi;
const allDataIds = [];

match = dataIdRegx.exec(yourString);
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  allDataIds.push(match[1]);
  match = dataIdRegx.exec(youtString);
}
```

Comment: Good solution !!

If I select more than one user, can i put the ID's in an array? Example ["2", "1"]
Thank you !